# Difference between iterating over the dictionary and iterating over .keys()

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

What's the difference between the following 2 pieces of code?

```py
D = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
for key in D:
    print(key)
```

```py
D = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
for key in D.keys():
    print(key)
```

Comment: They are functionally identical; the second one just makes it a bit more explicit just what you're iterating over.

Comment: One was written by a beginner and the other wasn't.

Comment: Practically speaking: none. Technically speaking: `dict.__iter__()` (which is the magic dunder function used in the first block) yields a `dict_keyiterator`, whereas `dict.keys()` yields a `dict_keys` instance, which in turn yields a `dict_keyiterator` as its `__iter__()`.

Comment: For most purposes that I know of, not much. `dict.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` of the keys, while iterating through a dictionary has it iterate by keys also. I would say its a lot more clear that you are going through the keys of the dictionary and adds to readability by humans.

Comment: @KellyBundy which one did you mean?

Comment: @rv.kvetch I meant "beginner" as in someone who doesn't realize the `.keys()` is unnecessary or still wants that kind of training wheels and who doesn't yet mind writing that over and over again because they haven't yet written dict-iterating code hundreds or thousands of times.

Comment: yeah, good point. I always skip the `.keys()` too, most of the time.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Maybe another reason: I think I started with Python 2, where that method created a list, so added even more overhead. Old-timers like that might still have an aversion to it because of that, while today's  beginners likely started with Python 3 and don't even know about that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both are identical by functionality and meaning.

Iteration "for key in D" will use the "dict_keys" iterable, same as using "for key in D.keys()"